# jQuery Chosen - search mask support

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using the jQuery Chosen plugin - very powerful, but I have a small problem with it.  I am wondering if there is a way to 'flatten' results in a search:

i.e.
If I type **0102** (no dashes) I would like:
**01-02-03-04**
to come up as a found result (and, similarly, entering 01-02 should work for that result as well)

I can't really use a mask because I have to also allow for searching of full words.

Anybody have any ideas on how this could possibly work?

Comment: What about making two queries when you input `0102` change the mechanism to search for `0102` and search `01-02` as well ?! then collect all results and display them together.

Comment: This could work - however I was hoping for something as simple as "ignore character in both search AND results" so the - simply wouldn't matter.